# QGIS change TIFF colors when importing

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, file-geodatabase

I have a RGB raster layer (3 bands) in a File Geodatabase in ArcGIS. I export this layer to TIFF and then import that in QGIS. The problem is that QGIS shows a different (darker) view than ArcGIS. I checked raster style and all bands are correctly set to Red-Green-Blue.
What can i do in QGIS to solve this?

What i see in ArcGIS: 
!([image: arcgis view])

what i see in QGIS:
[image: qgis view]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open `Layer Properties | Style` tab, then you may see the default setting for the `Contrast enhancement` being [No enhancement] . If it is the case please change it to [Stretch to MinMax] and click on [Load] button.

[image]

You can adjust the contrast and observe its effect by clicking on [Apply]. When you are satisfied with the appearance of the layer, [OK] to close.

This is required only once. When you close your project or remove the layer from your Layers panel, QGIS will automatically saves a supporting file `~.aux.xml` in the same place with your original image. Next time when you open your image again, QGIS will also read the `~.aux.xml` file to display the image as you have set it previously.

Comment: Thanks man. It works. Anyway, exported TIFF from ArcGIS contains aux.xml file and i don't know why QGIS deos not pay attention to that when importing.

Comment: Correction: As i understand, when removing layer, QGIS saves style in a *.qml file, not to *.aux.xml file.